# 15.10, Dell m3800 bluetooth not working

Tags: dell, touchpad, bluetooth

Picked up an m3800 refurb unit which shipped with Windows, but I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it and just about everything works perfectly on the laptop, but bluetooth is being a pain.

I have an Apple magic trackpad, and instructions I've followed in the past to get the trackpad working on my XPS13 don't work at all for me right now. When I try to scan for nearby devices, sometimes I'll find a few other systems in my office, but never find the trackpad at all, and sometimes a scan finds no devices at all.

I've tried two different trackpads, and the rig won't find either one. I've used the Fn+PrtScr combo to turn off wireless/bluetooth and turned it back on, and same thing happens (sometimes a scan sees devices, sometimes not, but trackpads are never seen).

My phone sees both trackpads just fine, so I know they're broadcasting for pairing mode.

I'm not familiar with what to reset on newer Ubuntu systems to try to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

rfkill shows nothing is blocked

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and hcitool scan shows nothing despite both trackpads being in pairing mode:

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
```

Per comments, more information:

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.132312] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.370096] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   21.405619] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   21.405635] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.405639] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.405641] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.405647] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.439886] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[   21.440778] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   21.465658] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
[   21.465663] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd not found
[   26.405222] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.405224] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.405227] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   27.583764] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   27.583769] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   27.583773] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

and

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:21f9 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`  It is likely a firmware issue

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31 I've added the new data. There's definitely some content in the dmesg output about direct firmware load not working (patch not found) Not sure how to proceed from there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work based on my other findings doing a search

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2pb41rhx65t9zi/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I saw the error message about which firmware file was missing, I was able to find an answer on this page:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(2015)

Even though I'm on an m3800 and not an XPS13, the Broadcom BT is the same. The instructions were clear about how to use cabextract on a downloaded Windows driver to get the firmware I needed.